# SQL to find the top selling product in April

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to find the top selling product in April from my database.
I have two tables called sales and salesline.

The sales table includes each sales throughout the year and the salesline table includes each product that was sold in each sale.

Sales table includes the following:

```
Sale_ID
Payment_ID
Ship_ID
Sales_Total
Date
Time
Cusotomer_ID
```

The salesline table includes:

```
Salesline_ID
Product_ID
SalePrice
Sale_ID
Payment ID
```

Thanks

Comment: `count` the number of lines, and `group by` Product_ID. If you want just for april you will have to join in the `sales` table and filter by date before counting.

Comment: top selling product based on `saleprice` column in `salesline` table?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find out the top selling product based on the `SalePrice` column of the `SalesLine` Table, you can go for the following query : -

```
    select sl.Product_ID,sum(sl.SalePrice) Sales
    from
    Sales s
    inner join
    salesline sl
    on s.Sale_ID = sl.Sale_ID
    where DATE_FORMAT(s.Date,'%m') = 4
    and DATE_FORMAT(s.Date,'%Y') = 2014
    group by sl.Product_ID
    order by Sales desc
    limit 10
```

This will give you the top 10 Selling products in April, 2014.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

If you want to check by the no of quantity sold:

```
select product_id, count(product_id)
from salesline
where sale_id in (select sale_id from sales where date BETWEEN '2013-04-01' AND '2013-04-30')
group by product_id
```